# Aurora Postgres Regional Cluster Read Replica Multiple Regions

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a RDS Database in Single Region with Multi AZ , This is Aurora Postgresql living in us-east-1 with read and writer endpoints. I now have a requirement where we would need to setup a separate region replica of this DB , it seems I can't do that for Aurora Postgres per what I am reading `Aurora PostgreSQL doesn't support cross-Region Aurora Replicas`.

We don't have a Global Database setup yet only Regional Cluster. How do I do this ?